# Getting data from webservice file not found

Tags: android, web-services

```
public class ODKortrijkWebservice extends AsyncTask<ODKortrijkInterface, Void, Void>{

Context context;
String myurl = "http://data.kortrijk.be/middenstand/winkels_markten";
URL url;

public ODKortrijkWebservice(Context context){
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(ODKortrijkInterface... params) {
    processXML(getData());
    return null;
}

private void processXML(Document data) {
    if(data!=null){
        Log.d("Root",data.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
    }
}

public Document getData(){
    try {
        url = new URL(myurl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xmlDoc = builder.parse(inputStream);
        return xmlDoc;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}}



07-27 17:11:56.867 17601-17726/com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://data.kortrijk.be/middenstand/winkels_markten
07-27 17:11:56.867 17601-17726/com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:206)
07-27 17:11:56.867 17601-17726/com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk W/System.err:     at com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk.Utill.ODKortrijkWebservice.getData(ODKortrijkWebservice.java:70)
07-27 17:11:56.868 17601-17726/com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk W/System.err:     at com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk.Utill.ODKortrijkWebservice.doInBackground(ODKortrijkWebservice.java:55)
07-27 17:11:56.868 17601-17726/com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk W/System.err:     at com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk.Utill.ODKortrijkWebservice.doInBackground(ODKortrijkWebservice.java:32)
07-27 17:11:56.868 17601-17726/com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
07-27 17:11:56.868 17601-17726/com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-27 17:11:56.868 17601-17726/com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-27 17:11:56.868 17601-17726/com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-27 17:11:56.868 17601-17726/com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-27 17:11:56.868 17601-17726/com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The website exists and is running. I'm calling this from my second activity, passing context as (this). WHat am I doing wrong that this isn't working? I've been struggling to get anything to work so I could really use some help

Edit: I've allowed internet connection in my android manifest, so that isn't the problem either. Something is wrong with my code, and I don't know what

Answer (score 0):

Lol.

The link should have been http://data.kortrijk.be/middenstand/winkels_markten.xml, hence why it didn't work. :')